# Dynamically generate Visual Studio solution and project files

Tags: visual-studio, templates

How can I dynamically generate Visual Studio solution and project files?
Like what `./configure` script does. Can accept parameters.
For example: in MyProject.sln.template

```
#if VS_2012
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format 12.00
#elseif VS_2010
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format 11.00
#elseif VS_2008
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format 10.00
#endif
#if VS_2012
Project("{12345678-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "Project1", "Project1\Project1.vcproj", "{98765432-E41A-4C56-B16F-263D2C6D6475}"
EndProject
#endif
```

What tools should I use? But I don't want to use `./configure` script.
It is better that the tools can be applicable to any kind of text files. Because I have other types of files to generate, not only solution/project files.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/) which generates workspaces/projects from a config script. Cmake is actually very powerful to maintain platform-independent build scripts. But it will suit your need.

Another option is a home-grown tool to create the sln/vcproj files. They are ultimately XML. There is probably no written documentation but you could reverse engineer from an existing workspace.

Comment: Can CMake manipulate any formats of text files? Such as a custom file format?

Comment: No, you need to write a cmake script file

Answer (score 0):

I have found this solution on github [Nager.TemplateBuilder](https://github.com/tinohager/Nager.TemplateBuilder) .

This example create a Windows Desktop Application with two nuget packages

```
//Configure Project
var demoProject = new ProjectInfo($"DemoProject", ProjectTemplate.WindowsClassicDesktopWindowsFormsApp);
demoProject.NugetPackages = new List<string> { "System.ServiceModel.NetTcp", "System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml" };

//Configure Solution
var folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var solutionInfo = new SolutionInfo("Test", folder);
solutionInfo.ProjectInfos.Add(demoProject);

//Start building machine
var buildingMachine = new SolutionBuildingMachine();
buildingMachine.Build(solutionInfo);
buildingMachine.Dispose();
```